# When enter obtained marks and total marks, percentage field is not automatically calculated

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, percentage

I want to calculate percentages and grades for students' educational qualifications. when obtained or total marks field input changed then automatically calculates and display percentage and grades

```
function PercCalculation() {
         //console.log("PercCalculation() called");
            var table = document.getElementById("gvEducationalQualifications");
            if (table != null) {
                var totalRows = table.rows.length;
                for (var i = 1; i < totalRows; i++) {
                    var row = document.getElementById("gvEducationalQualifications").rows[i];
                    var marksObtained = parseInt(row.cells[8].innerText);
                    var maxMarks = parseInt(row.cells[9].innerText);
                    var marksInput = row.cells[8].getElementsByClassName("mrksobteq")[0]; // assuming marks input is the first input element in the cell
                    var maxMarksInput = row.cells[9].getElementsByClassName("totalmarkseq")[0]; // assuming max marks input is the second input element in the cell

                    // attach the oninput event to the marks input field
                    marksInput.oninput = function () {
                    console.log("PercCalculation() called");
                    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
                    marksObtained = parseInt(this.value);
                    calculatePercentageAndGrade(row, marksObtained, maxMarks);
                    };
                    // attach the oninput event to the max marks input field
                    maxMarksInput.oninput = function () {
                    maxMarks = parseInt(this.value);
                    calculatePercentageAndGrade(row, marksObtained, maxMarks);
                    };
                    // calculate the initial percentage and grade
                    calculatePercentageAndGrade(row, marksObtained, maxMarks);
                }
            }
        }

        function calculatePercentageAndGrade(row, marksObtained, maxMarks) {
            var percentage = (marksObtained / maxMarks) * 100;
            row.cells[10].innerText = percentage.toFixed(2) + "%";
            var division;
            if (percentage >= 60) {
                division = "1st";
            }
            else if (percentage >= 45 && percentage < 60) {
                division = "2nd";
            }
            else if (percentage >= 30 && percentage < 45) {
                division = "3rd";
            }
            else {
                division = "Fail";
            }
            row.cells[11].innerText = division;
        }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.